# Slidetoggle to retain current state when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, which works but goes back to initial closed state whenever I reload or refresh page. I want retain last toggle state even after page reload. Can't seem to get my head around this problem.

My code is:

```
var $answers = $('.contentbar');
$(".titlebar").click(function () {
    var $ans = $(this).next(".contentbar").stop(true).slideToggle(500);
    $answers.not($ans).filter(':visible').stop(true).slideUp();
})
```

Comment: Use `localStorage` or `cookie` to save state.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin called [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Using that you can check if there's already a user-set accordion and based on the preference, you can show / hide stuff by default.

```
var $answers = $('.contentbar');
$(".titlebar").click(function () {
    if (!$.cookie('contentbar'))
        var $ans = $(this).next(".contentbar").stop(true).slideToggle(500);
    else
    {
        var $ans = $($.cookie('contentbar')).next(".contentbar").stop(true).slideToggle(500);
        $.cookie('contentbar', this);
    }
    $answers.not($ans).filter(':visible').stop(true).slideUp();
});
```